# Why is my Edittexts all over the app disappearing when I touch it

Tags: android, android-edittext

Something is wrong with the EditTexts in my app.
When I start typing into them, or when when I touch them, the line at the bottom of the EditText and the cursor become invisible.

Anyone has any idea why is this happening?
 XML for the EditText:

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:ems="5"
    android:id="@+id/etotp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvmobilenum"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    />
```

Please help somebody?

Comment: now it's better ... android:textCursorDrawable should be drawable not color

Comment: @Selvin without that also its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Set in the layout-file

```
android:cursorVisible="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:textCursorDrawable="@null` to your `EditText`

**UPDATE**

If you really need to change the EditText cursor color, define a drawable **cursor_drawable.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"  />
    </shape>
```

and set it to your `EditText` as

```
 android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_drawable.xml"
```

Comment: I tried with setting it as null or by removing the property itself. But it doesn't work.

Comment: This happens throughout the app.

Comment: Can you post your whole xml layout file.?